# celery pdb running inside docker container with changing listening port

Tags: python, celery, docker, pdb

Looking for advice on how I can run celery pdb inside my docker container while port forwarding so i can access from the outside world.

I am following the guide at http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/debugging.html

The issue I am facing is that even when I tell the container.

-e CELERY_RDB_HOST='0.0.0.0' -e CELERY_RDB_PORT='6900' -p 6900:6900.

And get to the breakpoint in the app, the port that actually gets open is not what I asked for so my port forward no longer is valid.... Eg. the port 6902 gets opened instead, and no matter what I ask the port to be, it changes again to not what I asked for.

I know it chooses from a list of 100 ports that it deems 'available' but not sure how to get around this problem.  Any advise would be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can run your container by specifying a range of ports (see http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports):

```
docker run -d -e CELERY_RDB_HOST='0.0.0.0' -p 6900-7000:6900-7000 celery
```

After that, when you hit your breakpoint, you just need to telnet into it:

```
telnet localhost 6902
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue, celery v4.4.7 in 11-2020.
Whatever I set to enviroment variable CELERY_RDB_PORT, I'll always get that nuber +2.
IE. If I set 9024, then rdb will listen on 9026.

Your docker command might look like this.

```
CELERY_RDB_HOST='0.0.0.0' -e CELERY_RDB_PORT='6900' -p 6902:6902
```

It's probably celery's bug.